What is implied volatility relationship with time?
My take on the question is that, with all else being equal, as time to expiry approaches, the option price decreases (due to theta). And since implied vol is the price of the option in volatility points, the implied vol should also decrease as TTE approaches.
But this doesn't make sense to me. Implied vol can be thought of as the market's expectation of the realize vol over the life of the option, in annualized vol. If all else remains equal, and the underlying continues moving at the same realize vol as usual, how could the implied vol decrease? Wouldn't that present an arbitrage opportunity, as implied vol keeps falling as TTE approaches, but the realize vol remains the same (since we assume ceteris paribus), thus creating a large disparity between implied vol and realized vol?

Why do you think future realized volatility would stay constant as the TTM decreases? The horizon for there to be volatility is shorter and naturally future realized volatility does decrease as the option approaches maturity.

Implied vol is not the markets expectation of future realized vol. If so, there wouldn't be a skew (smile/smirk). See https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76367/54838for details. Also, most of the time IV is larger for short ttm, which is also clearly visible in the vol surface shown in the link above.

I don't think we should close this question actually, sounds like a fair quant question to me (maybe I am not that smart to recognise that this is a basic finance question).

It is well known that the value of At the money options is proportional to $\sigma\sqrt{T-t}$ where $\sigma$ is the implied annualized volatility.  So as time evolves, the value falls naturally due to the square root factor.  The volatility factor may or may not move with time, depending on market conditions and supply and demand for options.

Hey @dm63, doesn't this contradict with what AKdemy is saying? which is that IV increases as TTM decreases (ceteris paribus - but mostly due to the spot being constant). And I recall I did perform some testing before that showed what he said was true (and contradicted the IV term structure, which shows mostly decreasing IV as the TTM decreases).

So you're saying that there's no theoretically clear relationship between implied vol and TTE? It may or may not increase/decrease and will ultimately depend on the market conditions? So if we hold all other params constant (market conditions remain same etc.), implied vol would not change at all when TTE decreases?

Yes I am saying there is no clear relationship between TTM and implied vol for ATM options. Let me give examples: an option which expires one day after the Presidential election will probably see IV increase as expiration approaches , since there may be a large movement on the last day.  On the other hand an option that is purchased one day before the election, but has two weeks  before expiration, may experience a drop in IV after the event is ‘out of the way’.  I do not believe this contradicts @AKDemy who is pointing out the weaknesses of BS in fitting the tails of the distribution.
